# Cloud9 error with opening .settings file on windows

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

I have installed the Cloud9 on windows. It starts normally (maybe normally. i'm a beginner with it):

```
F:\cloud9>node server.js
connect plugin start
Connect server listening at http://localhost:3131
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  auth
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  git
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  gittools
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  hg
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  npm
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  filelist
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  search
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  revisions
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  settings
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  shell
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  state
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  watcher
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  node-runtime
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  npm-runtime
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  python-runtime
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  apache-runtime
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  ruby-runtime
IDE SERVER PLUGIN:  php-runtime
Started 'F:\cloud9\configs\default'!
IDE server initialized. Listening on localhost:3131
```

But when i open localhost:3131, i see the cloud9 workarea with message popup:

```
Received folowing error from server:
"ENOENT, open 'F:\\F:\\cloud9\\.settings~13913313647147-1'"
```

And in console:

```
Error: ENOENT, open 'F:\F:\cloud9\.settings~1393313647147-1'
[CLIENT ERROR] { agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36',
  type: 'C9 SERVER EXCEPTION',
  message:
   { type: 'error',
     sid: -1,
     code: 500,
     message: 'ENOENT, open \'F:\\F:\\cloud9\\.settings~1393313647147-1\'' } }
```

I understand that i need to fix the only string in server code maybe. But i cant't find out where to do that.

Comment: i'm experiencing the same problem here. After i manually edited the outdated `gnu-tools` package to look for utilities in windows, starting cloud9 throws the error i tried to search in settings module of cloud9 but i can't find where the path string is created and gets the driver letter two times instead of one.. maybe its a jsDAV bug